# How to get a SIGNATURE LIST from *.dll(*.exe,*.msi)-file programmatically?

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I'm trying to get a signature **list** as Window's-properties window (as a screenshot).
I need to get **Name of singer**, **Digest algorithm** and **Timestamp**.
[image: File property window]
P.S. I don't need a **Sertificate info**!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use signtool.exe util from Windows SDK

```
signtool.exe verify /all /pa <path>
```